# How are Optimzed graphics games developed in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d-games

Although this is not a direct programming question, but it would be great if someone can share  knowledge

I am very much impressed with the graphics based android games especially "Subway surfer". Can some one explain

1. Using which tool these graphics are developed and incorporated in Android and iOS. Is it OpenGL ES ?
2. Can someone point to free opensource games sources which has amazing graphics, which can be used as a reference?

Any related info would be of great help

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES is probably the most popular solution because it is pretty fast and supports 3D drawing. Not to mention iOS supports OpenGL ES too (AFAIK) which allows one to develop a cross-platform graphics layer. [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) is a popular platform for developing games on Android that sits on top of OpenGL ES, and the [example apps](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) show off some pretty cool graphics.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES is the best solution for developing serious 3D games on Android, but be aware that large projects are usually done in native code, not Java.  This article explains the reasons in detail:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

The sample programs provided with the Android SDK and NDK are really incomplete.  A much better example is Replica Island:

http://replicaisland.net/